# C# checked overflow

Tags: c#, winforms, overflow, checked

I have made a calculator with C# (in VS 2008), but I can't understand why the

```
checked{iCurrent = (iCurrent * 10) + i;}
```

can check the overflow, can someone explain this? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
 try
    {
         //get the typed
         long iCurrent=long.Parse(textOut.Text);
         if(bNumBegins)
         {
             iCurrent = i;
             bNumBegins = false;
         }
         else
         {
             //check whether overflow
             checked{iCurrent = (iCurrent * 10) + i;}
         }
         textOut.Text = iCurrent.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: are you asking how `checked` works internally?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you not understand what the checked block is for? Or what will happen? Note that you don't need a new block for it - I'd write that as `iCurrent = checked ((iCurrent * 10) + i)`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.110).aspx you have everything in it

Comment: "are you asking how checked works internally? – David Pilkington 25 mins ago" @DavidPilkington Yes, why need * 10? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [`checked` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) you ask the compiler to automatically generate code that will test whether [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow) has occurred after arithmetic operations. If overflow is detected, an `OverflowException` is thrown.

The default in C# is to not check for such overflow when performing arithmetic operations. The default can be changed to check all operations. Regardless of the default, the `checked` and `unchecked` keywords can be used to selectively check or ignore overflow as needed.

Comment: I can't understand why that need * 10? I don't understand the arithmetic means. Can you explain it? Thanks. I'm sorry for my bad English. @c45207

Comment: "arithmetic" means things like addition +, subtraction -, multiplication *, and division /.

Answer (score 0):

**@DavidPilkington Yes, why need * 10? Thanks**

I think that you are confused here.

The code is multiplying the `iCurrent` variable by 10 and then adding one. This is the desired effect that the coder wanted. The `checked` keyword is used to make sure that there is no `OverflowException`.

The `*10` is not needed for the checked, the check is "needed" for the operation to ensure that the number is not too large.

Here is the MSDN documention on [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx). I suggest you read through it and the examples to gain a better understanding.